# Native server 2012 R2 driver for APC 3000VA (network connected)

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012

Is there a native driver available for an APC network connected UPS on windows server 2012 R2 hyper-V?

All I can find from APC is Powerchute.  Problem with that is it seems to require Java installed, that just doesn't feel right.  I would prefer to keep the server clean and don't want to be forced into having Java installed on a server.

Answer (score 1):

***Java versus a clean shutdown...?***

If you wish to use the PowerChute software for your UPS, you'll need a JRE. You could simply make sure your runtime is high enough to not require a shutdown... :) but honestly, if you need the full functionality provided by the APC shutdown software, you're going to have to install Java.

I do think the OS will [recognize the UPS via the USB port](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/10/22/setting-up-hyper-v-with-a-ups.aspx), though. Check the device manage and power support to see if your APC unit is recognized.

Comment: +1 heh...great minds...I was going to link that same article.

Comment: Problem is getting windows to recognise the UPS.  It is network connected, not USB.  Doesn't actually have a USB connection, only network or serial port and Win 2012 doesn't support serial port UPSs any longer.

Comment: Then: [Java](https://www.java.com/en/).

Comment: If it is a USB PSU and you don't want to use PowerChute, there is always http://www.apcupsd.org/

Comment: Unfortunately apcups.org does not seem to support Server 2012.  Also the UPS is network connected no USB connection present.

Comment: You have several options for a direct-connected UPS. But for a network-based device, you need to use the vendor's ecosystem. In your case, ***that means installing Java!!*** - Just accept it, suck it up and do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid installing the APC software on the server, you could install it on a management station and then run a batch file to shutdown the server on runtime exceeded.